# DecimalFormat class unnessarily giving roundfigured numbers

Tags: java, android, decimalformat

I want to display GPS coordinates upto just 6 decimal places. e.g. if my GPS location is something like `x.yyyyyyyyyy` I want to display just `x.yyyyyy` and for this I use `DecimalFormat` class. But, if the number is like `8.3456709012`, the output for the following code is like `8.34568`

```
_yPos = 8.3456709012;
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.######");
String yCoord = decimalFormat.format(_yPos);
```

whereas the expected output is `8.345670`. Can anybody show me a way to do this?

Comment: Are you sure that you want `8.345670` and not `8.345671`?  The latter would be the conventional way to show less digits (i.e. rounding), so going for truncation behaviour instead is unusual and (IMHO) should only be done if the application domain really needs it.

Comment: Also, if I run your example (assuming `_yPos` is a `double`) I get an output of `8.345671`, not `8.34568`.  Are you sure this is the code you're actually running?  Your problem may lie elsewhere.

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle : Nice observation. But of course, that's not the actual code, I was gettings GPS coordinates from the location receiver. I gave just an example that it is rounding it off. Anyways, thanks. `0.000000` helped me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `"0.000000"` as the formatting code.

The character # is for "Digit, zero shows as absent": http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Also, you have to set the rounding mode to `DOWN` if you really want the output `8.345670` rather than `8.345671`:

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.000000");
decimalFormat.setRoundingMode(java.math.RoundingMode.DOWN);
```

Comment: thats not the answer of his question.. he doesn't required rounding.. what will be the result of 8.3456709012?

Comment: @Shehzad According to the OP "the expected output is `8.345670`", so it looks like he does require rounding.

Comment: his required output is 8.345670 but "0.000000"?-> 8.345671

Answer (score 2):

Joni Salonen's answer suggests how you can preserve  trailing zeros, but the coordinates will still be half rounded as the default rounding mode is RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN.

You can set the rounding mode by using

```
decimalFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
```

This method is available since 1.6

Refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setRoundingMode%28java.math.RoundingMode%29

Comment: that really isent the solution. the OP just wants the trailing 0 to be shown

Comment: the opener has also specified that he is getting "roundfigured numbers" and i assume that this is the way to fix that..edited the answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

isent it new DecimalFormat("#.#####0") ?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html