# Grails: format of coordinates are not shown correctly

Tags: grails

I'm using the Google Maps Api v3, but this question is related to the Grails default formatting. In my domain class I have:

```
Float latitude;
Float longitude;
```

The Google Maps correct coordinates are:

```
36.5270612, -6.288596200000029
```

Unfortunately, in the **show**, it shows:

```
365.270.624, -6.288.596.088.651.776
```

-- show code:

```
<p id="latitude"><g:fieldValue  bean="${bestInstance}" field="latitude"/></p>
```

Unfortunately, the **edit** is not very nice either. It shows:

```
3.65270624E8, -6.2885961E15
```

The following solution from [here](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Remove-commas-from-integer-numbers-gt-1000-td1569235.html), scares me because of the 3.65270624 **E8** format:

```
${bestInstance.latitude.encodeAsHTML()}
```

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10293228/decimalformat-class-unnessarily-giving-roundfigured-numbers), that we should **round to down**. The following code **should work**:

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.000000");
decimalFormat.setRoundingMode(java.math.RoundingMode.DOWN);
```

From [documentation I found out:  **formatNumber**](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/formatNumber.html). I tried the following code (but the result is the same that the show):

```
<g:formatNumber format="0.000000" number="${bestInstance.latitude}" type="number" />
```

**How could we do the same in a GSP file?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem usually is that the input is a string. We must have special careful checking if a value is a number or an string . My solution:

1) Reduce the precision of the coordenates before to save them (if not, weird things happens!):

```
def create()
    (...)
    case 'POST':
        (...)
        params.putAt('latitude', reducePrecision(params.latitude))
        params.putAt('longitude', reducePrecision(params.longitude))
        (...)

private def reducePrecision(coordenate) {
    coordenate= Float.parseFloat(coordenate);
    return ( (float) ( (int) coordenate* 100000 ) / 100000 );       
}
```

2) In show.gsp, get the value doing (both ways worked for me):

```
<div id="latitude">${alojamientoInstance.latitude}</div>
<div id="longitude">${alojamientoInstance.longitude.encodeAsHTML()}</div>
```

Comment: math on Floating Point's is dangerous.  You should probably be using BigDecimal instead of Float.

Answer (score 0):

I'm passing latitude and logitude from the params and I'm using them as show below:

```
[ ${params.float('celat', defLat)}, ${params.float('celng', defLong)}]
```

where **defLat** and **defLong** are some default values and this works great

Comment: I typed: `def a = params.float('232.2323')`. a is null. If you mean with `'celat'`, the name of a param, the only param in show is id...

Comment: Yes, celat and celng are params in my example